# jQuery uncheck radio button based on class

Tags: jquery, class, radio-button, unchecked

Is it possible to uncheck a radio button based on class?

```
$('#button').click(function () {

    $("input:radio[class^='.radio2']").each(function(i) {
      this.checked = false;
        });

});
```

JsFiddle = http://jsfiddle.net/nPgyd/1/

This doesn't appear to work.

Comment: Try using  `$(this).prop('checked', false);`

Comment: No joy, maxART below suggested but no joy.

Comment: I actually suggested it first ^^

Comment: @shivam, dont get jumpy buddy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HERE is your solution.
You only need to remove the braces to compare the class

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nPgyd/4/)**

```
 $("input:radio[class^=radio2]").each(function(i) {
```

Comment: Works in the jsFiddle but when I apply to my actual code it doesn't!  How odd.

Comment: I would have to see your actual code for tht. maybe theres a typo or something

Comment: Also you code has a bug. you have given all 4 buttons the same value. Is that deliberate?

Comment: All sorted - was a different error in my code.  Perfect thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This might be helpful for you.

```
$('#button').click(function () {
    $("input:radio.radio2").each(function(i) {
            $(this).attr('checked',false);
    });

});
```

Check the link...

http://jsfiddle.net/nPgyd/13/

Answer (score 1):

Try

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nPgyd/5/)

```
$('#button').click(function () {

    $(".radio2").each(function(i) 
     {
          this.checked = false;
     });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, the syntax required is not nearly as complex as that.

```
$('#button').click(function () 
{    
    $(".radio2").each(function(i) 
    {
          this.checked = false;
    });                
});
```

Or if you want only inputs with the class radio2 to be affected:

```
$('#button').click(function () 
{    
    $("input.radio2").each(function(i) 
    {
          this.checked = false;
    });                
});
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nPgyd/2/)

Comment: It's this bit that is key `class^=` as in the live app things are often have `radio-`. Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this?

```
$('#button').click(function () {

    $("input[type='radio'].radio2").each(function () {
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
    });

});
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nPgyd/14/)**